# SQL Запросы

Tags: база-данных, sql

Посчитать количество язвенников, поступивших в текущем году. Вот мой вариант,

```
SELECT count(diagnoz) FROM pacienti WHERE diagnoz='yazva' AND data_postupleniya >= DATE()
```

но мне выдает количество всех язвенников, а не только тех, которые поступили в текущем году, подскажите, как правильно сделать

Comment: в каком формате у тебя дата хранится?

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить про MSSQL:

```
SELECT count(diagnoz) FROM pacienti WHERE diagnoz='yazva' AND YEAR(data_postupleniya) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```